# ember model.reload() is not a function?

Tags: ember.js, model

I want to reload my model in my controller,and I read the document from [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload)

so I defined the action:reload in my controller and route both,such as:

```
 reload:function(){
     this.get('model').reload();
   }
```

when I triggered the action use `this.send('reload')`,it comes out the error **`this.get(...).reload is not a function`**,so did I misunderstand the document?

Comment: try `this.controller.get('model').reload();`

Comment: show your full route and controller code and post your ember and ember-data version, please

Comment: DEBUG: Ember                   : 1.13.3  
DEBUG: Ember Data              : 1.13.5  
DEBUG: jQuery                  : 1.11.3  
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth       : 0.8.0  
 DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth Torii : 0.8.0

Comment: I'm having the same problem when I call `this.controller.get('model').reload()` I get `this.controller.get(...).reload is not a function`

Answer (score 8):

Check that your model is not a collection. You can only reload a record. If your model is  a collection you should do the following:

```
reload:function(){
     this.get('model').forEach(function(record){
        record.reload();
     });

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 actions: {
 reload: function() {
   this.controller.get('model').reload().then(function(model) {
     // do something with the reloaded model
   });
  }
 }
});
```

And in your controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 actions: {
  reload_model: function() {
     this.send('reload');
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: are you calling somewhere `reload_model` action?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh a model in newer Ember versions (v2.3+?), you may be best off using `getOwner()` to get the corresponding route and `refresh()` the model by re-firing the `model()` hook, so you're not dependent on model-specific methods (if the model is the result of a `findAll()`, for example, it won't have a `reload()` method).

Example using native class/decorator style (current as of 3.10):

```
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { getOwner } from '@ember/application';

export default class MyController extends Controller {
  @action async reload() {
    // should probably be called refresh() for consistency
    return getOwner(this).lookup('route:my').refresh();
  }
}
```